# this.$el and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette

I'm trying to do something deceptively simple -- adding a class to the active backbone element. The code I want to use is:

```
 this.$el.addClass('classIWant');
```

However, this doesn't work all the time. Sometimes it seems to, but not all the time. However, this always works.

```
 var id = this.$el.attr('id');

 $('#' + id).addClass('classIWant');
```

Obviously I don't want the second example, as it relies so heavily on HTML and the DOM. Is there any reason why the first shouldn't work, or am I missing something else?

Comment: I see no reason the second should work while the first does not.

Comment: console.log() what `this` is referring to.

Comment: Are you sure that you're calling the container method with the right context (the `this` variable)?

Comment: You might be hitting a race condition. Please post your complete code

Comment: Wouldn't you happen to have several elements with the same id? That's the only thing I can think of that would match your problem.

Comment: I shouldn't, as the ID is a unique ID. @JoeBeuckman, I logged 'this', and all looks normal -- it's the actual element, and I can't seem to find anything wrong or out of the normal with it

Comment: if `this` is an element then there is certainly something wrong, `this` should be an instance of Backbone.View

Comment: Apologies - I mistyped. I was referring to this.$el

Comment: Can you provide the full structure of the rest of the code so that we can see how it fits into the the view?

Comment: Have you solved the problem already? Let us know what was wrong!

Comment: What is the problem exactly? You get an error or it doesn't add the class?

Comment: I don't get the class, no error.

Answer (score 1):

Seems `this` points to something wrong. If you are running this code in function `myFunc`, then just add to `initialize` next line:

```
_.bindAll(this, 'myFunc');
```

And got with you first approach, `this.$el.addClass('classYouWant')`.

Comment: If `this` points to something wrong, why would `this.$el.attr('id');` work?

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
this.$el.addClass('classIWant');
```

but only if it is present within your onRender() function or any functions that are called after onRender() is. If you have this code in your initialize function then it will not work as the dom for that view has not yet been generated